# how to "save current displayed text" in cmd windows 10

Tags: cmd.exe

is there such a command to do this:

"To export the history, I was able to simply right click the window, click "select all" then CTRL-C to copy. I then CTRL-P pasted into a text editor."

i faced a issue, the application is executed in cmd  using batch command, it will count very fast from 0% to 100%, 
when i do >log.txt, the log become a 2GB file because it record all 0.001% 0.002% 0.003%......... until 100%

but i dont need those intermediate echo, i just want to save the "final" text ,which is less than 10 line.

is there such a command to "save current displayed echo" into a file at the end of execution? such that i add this line at end of my batch and it will save "whatever showing on cmd display" into a text file?

if i can just use a command to do select all-->copy-->paste into a text, that will be the exact thing i want, however i could not find such command to add into batch

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Redirect application output to NUL:

```
app 2>&1>NUL
```

or output error to a separate file for it:

```
app 1> NUL 2>> apperr.txt
```

Then redirect the stream from the batch file to a log file:

```
batch.cmd >> output.txt
```

or clipboard:

```
batch.cmd | clip
```